# Going from $\Lambda$ to a prime count

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

A 1997 paper of Étienne Fouvry and Henryk Iwaniec, [Gaussian primes](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa79/aa7935.pdf), concerns the prevalence of primes that are of the form $n^2+p^2$ for prime $p$.  The asymptotic result is

$$\sum_{n^2+p^2\le x}\Lambda(p)\Lambda(n^2+p^2)=kx+O(x(\log x)^{-A})$$

with $A>0$ arbitrary and
$$k=2\prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{(p-1)(p-\chi(p))}\right)\approx2.1564103447695$$
where $\chi(n)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$ is the nontrivial character mod 4.  The big-O constant is uniform, depending only on the choice of $A$.

I would like to use this to find an asymptotic formula for $f(x):=|\mathcal{P}\cap\{n^2+p^2\le x\}|$.  It looks like

$$f(x)=2k\frac{x}{(\log x)^2}(1+o(1))$$

but I'm not quite sure of my derivation, nor even of how to interpret the original result (are duplicate representations double-counted or not?).  Can someone confirm or deny my calculation?

---

Bonus question: were Fouvry & Iwaniec the first to show that there are infinitely many of these primes?  They cite Rieger, Coleman, Duke, and Pomykala as related results but none had both prime restrictions.

Comment: If $p$ and $n^2+p^2$ are prime in the first sum, why bother with using the vonmangoldt function? You seem to have written their result down incorrecty

Comment: @Ethan: In the sum $p$ is prime but $n^2+p^2$ need not be. See (1.5) in the paper I linked to, noting that $\ell$ is constrained to be prime.

Comment: $\Lambda(l)\Lambda(n^2+l^2)=0$, unless $l$ and $n^2+l^2$ are both prime powers, I don't see where it says $l$ is a prime.

Comment: @Ethan: Last paragraph of page 249.

Comment: They are proving there are an infinite number of primes where $l$ is a prime, that doesn't imply that l is a prime in the latter sum.

Comment: @Charles Judging from (1.4) I don't see think $l$ is meant to always be prime.  However, (1.3) seems so general that one could just as easily restrict $l$ to be prime by setting $\lambda_l$ to be the prime indicator function.  Also, the amount of duplicate representation should be minimal since the sum of squares decomposition is unique for primes, so only something like $p^2+2^2$ gets counted twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the bonus question, the review in Math Reviews says the authors prove this result, and the reviewer doesn't mention anyone else having done it. I would take this as evidence that Fouvry and Iwaniec were the first.